# EnhanceIO installation error

Tags: drivers, make

I'm trying to install [EnahaceIO](https://github.com/stec-inc/EnhanceIO).

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.19.0-51-generic (buildd@lgw01-21) (gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) ) #58-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 26 21:22:26 UTC 2016
```

I follow the instructions explained in [install.txt](https://github.com/stec-inc/EnhanceIO/blob/master/Install.txt), but I get the following error:

```
$ sudo make install
make -C /lib/modules/3.19.0-51-generic/build M= modules V=0
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-51-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h'.  Stop.
arch/x86/Makefile:180: recipe for target 'archheaders' failed
make[1]: *** [archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-51-generic'
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: In kernels 3.15, 3.18 I think Kernel parameters were shuffled around. Anyway you need to get new version from github.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I've got the last version of EnhanceIO from github.

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/stec-inc/EnhanceIO/issues and ascertain that you are running a supported kernel? `uname -a`

Comment: @ElderGeek he did a 'cat /proc/version' which is just as good as 'uname -a'

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks, Clearly I missed that bit. makes the `uname -a` superfluous  ;-)

Comment: @Mehrshad let me know if its not fixed by Friday. Then I'll configure my mSata III for 60gb cache and ressurect the EnhanceIO code from the Windows Intel RST bricked HDD and repeat your installation under 3.19 this weekend. Otherwise if you get it fixed great :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanx, I changed my linux kernel headers to `3.13.11-991-generic` and reinstall the EnhanceIO. Now it's working. :D

Comment: I started EnhanceIO at 3.13 too but I believe it was with 3.15 it broke and I had to get the github patches from Jan 2015 I think it was. Original code was from 2012 I believe. Do you want write your answer and mark it solved or leave the question open?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I don't like answering my own question. :/

Comment: @Mehrshad, its like talking to yourself? LOL.. I'll write something later on about parameters?

Comment: @Mehrshad As discussed an answer to your question posted below. We never established **how long** it would take :)